# fastcgi_cache_key exclude some args in request uri

Tags: regex, nginx, fastcgi

My fastcgi_cache_key is:

```
fastcgi_cache_key "$host$request_method$request_uri";
```

My $request_uri has timestamp and signature in it:

```
 /abc/xyz?product_id=10529125896&shop_id=17224077&shop=abc.com&path_prefix=%2Fa%2Fcomment&timestamp=1503044416&signature=882102c51c7b7bd4c5d8521a6565fc70c27b908547316f1123eb4af13b19f2da
```

So, the cache always MISS (because it has different timestamp and signature). My question is:

I want to create new var and use that var for fastcgi_cache_key. That var will has something like this:

myvar

```
/abc/xyz?product_id=10529125896&shop_id=17224077&shop=abc.com
```

fastcgi_cache_key will like this:

```
fastcgi_cache_key "$host$request_method$myvar";
```

How can I do that ? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it.

```
if ($request_uri ~ "([^\?]*)\?(.*)timestamp=([^&]*)&?(.*)") {
  set $args $2$4;
}
fastcgi_cache_key "$host$request_method$args";
```

This will remove the timestamp. You can either modify the pattern to ignore one more field or you can use it twice to remove the field from `$args`.

Next option is to use `openresty` or Nginx with lua which allows you to execute Lua script in your code. `if` conditions are not considered good. But then having lua increases your software requirement

Comment: Thanks Tarun Lalwani